# How can I combine these meshes and rigs without needing to reparent everything?

Tags: mesh, rigging, objects, armature, origin

I have attempted to  rig this model but I cannot combine the right side with the body. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and the proper way to join models like this?

I have tried applying scale/rot/loc, setting to delta, and parenting but nothing seems to work correctly.

https://easyupload.io/vx9zed

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your armature and mesh objects are cut in two halves. So you should join the left part of the armature to the right part, and same thing for the objects. The problem is that for the moment left and right bones have exactly the same names, so when you'll join, the bones will change their name and they won't be able to control the mesh anymore.

What you need to do first is correctly name your bones. Remove one side of your armature. For the remaining side: Name the bones with the good suffixe, for example the left leg must be named Leg_L or Leg.R. When you'll have finished with this side, go into the *Armature* panel and *Symmetrize*, you'll automatically create the mirrored part with the opposite suffixe (Leg_R and so on for the other ones).

Now join your 2 mesh objects, remove the existing vertex groups, parent the object to the armature *With Empty Groups*, go in *Edit* mode, select all and recalculate the normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, select the part you want and assign it to the correct vertex group.